# Api-Platform "No operations defined in spec!" in Symfony 5.1 dev system

Tags: api-platform.com, symfony5

I am using Symfony 5.1.8 in an existing project and installed Api Platform, version 2.5.7:

```
composer req api
```

I added an @ApiResource() Annotation to one of my entity classes.

When calling the /api/ route there is always just a message saying "No operations defined in spec!". **The problem does only occur on my dev system (php 4.7.11, macOS Catalina 10.15.6, xdebug... ).** So I do not think it's a configuration problem...

When I deploy this to my testsystem (debian with docker containers) everything works as expected - there are shown 6 resources I can interact with.

I tried to update my composer dependencies, clear the cache several times, clear the cache folder... nothing of this helped.

When calling

```
bin/console debug:router
```

on my test system, I get all 6 resources. In my dev system there are no routes shown.

Do you have any ideas where to start debugging to better understand the problem?

What are further interesting details?

Edit:
It works in the dev system when changing the environment to "test". But I do still not have a clue, why...

regards

Stephan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer.
I am using redis for system cache, so the deletion of the cache folder (./var/cache) didn't help.

A normal cache:clear didn't help, too:

```
bin/console cache:clear
```

But a cache clear of the **system cache** did the trick:

```
bin/console cache:pool:clear cache.system_clearer
```